# How to solve error message: "Failed to map the path '/'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've searched and searched on Google, and I can't find anything that even seems applicable to my situation, let alone solves the problem. It doesn't matter which address in my website I try to navigate to (even addresses that don't exist give this error instead of a 404), I get the exact same message (the path is always '/'). Any ideas?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Failed to map the path '/'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +336

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to map the path '/'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11556592
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4813333

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

**UPDATE:** I went back to the site a few minutes after posting this--made no changes to code or configuration--and the error went away. I'm really baffled, but it is no longer a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the error message. There is either a problem with IIS or with your ASP.NET applications (betting this). You are going to need to post your code, tell us more about the problem. How many websites of yours are affected? What changes have you performed recently? When did the problem start?

Comment: have you got anything in your web.config file or .asax files?

Comment: Did you modify the properties of your virtual directories or the IIS app pool? Have you tried restarting IIS? Are all of the appropriate files still present on the server?

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I let it sit and came back and its fine. Keep the question up for reference.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I had the same issue (MVC 4) under IIS 7.  It turned out that the App Pool identity didn't have the correct authorization to the site's path.

Comment: Me too.  Thanks!  To clarify further, I ended up changing the app pool identity for my web service from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "Network Service".

Comment: Thanks! Renamed a site and got the error, iisreset did the trick!

Comment: Go to the topmost level of the tree in IIS, and click Restart (under Manage Server). Fixed this same problem for me, using the IIS GUI.

Comment: For my case I just needed to reset the IIS :)

Comment: Just re-enter Identity in ProcessModel for app-pool and everything works. Thanks for help!

Comment: I am getting this with IIS express. how to set up/fix it with IIS express? is it same like IIS? thanks

Comment: Thanks @ruffen I got the same error with site renaming. Fixed by resetting iis.

Answer (score 266):

restarting IIS solved the same issue in my case. Seems like something fails in IIS. Didn't worth my panic, either.

IIS 7.5, btw.

Comment: open cmd prompt and run 'iisreset'.  As prosaic as it sounds, it worked!

Comment: +1 Helped me. Was caused after I renamed the "Default Web Site" to another name. (Stoping and starting IIS in management console solved it.)

Comment: +1 Started after removing default site.  Fixed with iisreset as suggested.

Comment: Damn, such a nuisance. Really worth trying to restart, before verifying each and other config file, don't worth panic.

Answer (score 66):

You don't have to reset IIS, you can just recycle the app pool.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. A very slick solution. Why rebuild the whole tower if rebuilding just a room can work.

Answer (score 32):

Today when I renamed the default website, under which my MVC application was hosted, I started getting that error too. But I restarted IIS and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem — I renamed the site within IIS and I started getting this error. Recycling the app pool made it go away (and restarting IIS would automatically recycle the app pools, of course). Most odd.

Answer (score 5):

I also have same issue. In my case working on InstalledSheild / InstalledAware, to make setup of web service. After setup run the above error comes, while resolve issue when check, found that IIs default website path remove after setup run.

So I just add path as below step.

1. Go to Command prompt -> type InetMgr
2. Its open IIS, go to 'Default Web Site' -> Advanced Settings (at right side menu)
   [image]
3. Go to Physical Path and paste this things - '%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot' as below 
   [image]

Comment: This solution worked for me where I was installing a site from a Windows Installer. My Physical Path setting was originally "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" which was the correct path, but after changing the value to "%SystemDrive%\Inetpub\wwwroot" the installer completed successfully.

Answer (score 5):

Just start cmd and run the command `iisreset` and error will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

These samples run in server. So either the Windows user must have READ/WRITE permissions or must run the sample in Administrator mode.

Try running the sample in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had misnamed some virtual directories in IIS Manager. After fixing them, I was good.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:
1. Right click on "Default web site"
2. Choose Advance settings
3. Setup Physical Path to C:\inetpub\wwwroot
4. Click OK.
5. Browse the Default web site. --> It works.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a specific application and not the entire IIS site. In my case, access to the application directory was not the problem. Instead, I needed to give the application pool a recycle.

I think this was related to how the application was deployed and the IIS settings were set (done via scripts and a deployment agent).

Comment: This was my issue as well.  I had renamed the name of the site under the Sites list in the left panel of IIS and then the site stopped working until I recycled it's application pool.

Answer (score 1):

This line (top of the stack trace) is telling you there is something wrong which the hosting configuration.

```
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +336
```

How is your server set up?  Have you checked the config files?

I'd search through them specifically for any settings or attributes which have the single value "/".

Answer (score 1):

Changing pool from `ASP.NET v4.0` to `Framework4` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I Think this is because of  IIS is unable to find the root folder. i.e wwwroot. Restarting the IIS wont be helpful in some scenarios.
if the root path has changed, you should bring it back to %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot

by right clicking sites node in IIS and changing physical path to the above one.

and make sure that your application pool is asp.net v4.0 and  running in integrated mode

Answer (score 1):

i have tried following solution and it had work for me
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
right click on Devenv.exe
in Compablity tab --> Privilage Level --> click on Run this Program as an Adminstrator
If as for the Admin Password Provide it

if it is already selected deselect it and again select it
-->Apply-->OK

restart the VS application
and Publish your website again

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error because I happened to be opening a website project over a mapped network drive `z:\folder` instead of connecting via a UNC path `\\server\path\folder`.  Once I opened the project from the UNC path it built just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this after updating to Windows 10 Fall Creators edition version 1709. None of the solutions above worked for me. I was able to fix the error this way:

1. Go to “Control Panel” > “Administrative Tools” > “IIS Manager”.
2. Choose “Change .NET Framework Version” from the “Actions” in the
   right margin.
3. I chose the latest version shown and clicked “OK”.

If IIS Manager is not available under Administrative Tools, you can enable it this way:

1. Press the Windows key and type "Turn Windows Features On or Off"
   then select the search result.
2. In dialog that appears, check the box by “Internet Information
   Services” and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to data in your **web.config** file. E.g. a backslash in a domain username.

```
userName='domain\user'.
```

Comment: And how could that cause this problem? Some more info would be quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

~I've gone to the Internet Information Services Manager

~Click the sites

~Right click on your website

~Click Manage Website > Advance Settings

~Change the application pool to DefaultAppPool

And it works fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to run the ASP.Net precompiler, it turned out that I was not opening the command prompt as administrator. Once I did, I was able to run the asp.net compiler successfully.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make sure that **all IIS features are installed**. So went to add remove programs in the control panel and clicked on add remove windows features and selected all options except IIS 6 console compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

Executing the command `iisreset` (cmd with elevated rights) fixed this issue for me.