# Failed to map the path '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.Net website solution in Visual Studio, and when trying to `Server.MapPath(@"\");`I receive the following error. I know this question has been asked before but I am yet to find a solution that has worked for me. Any ideas would be great.

```
Failed to map the path '/'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.

Source Error: 


Line 10:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 11:     {
Line 12:       string directory = Server.MapPath(@"\");
Line 13:       Response.Write(directory);
Line 14:     }

Source File: c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MMCR\About.aspx.cs    Line: 12 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.]
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +8937646
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath) +42
   System.Web.VirtualPath.MapPathInternal() +4
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +107
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) +37
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path) +99
   About.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Josh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MMCR\About.aspx.cs:12
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Comment: what you trying to do here `Response.Write(directory)`..?

Answer (score 5):

If all of the others suggested solution if not working it means that your Visual Studio doesn't have a administrative privileged.

Hence you may run the Visual Studio "Run as Administrator" and try to execute once again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Server.mapPath("~/");
```

Comment: I may need another question for this.. All though this does return a path, I have two websites in the same solution. Located in "WebSites\MMCR\" and "WebSites\MMCR_Admin\" respectively and I want to gain access from one to the other. I have got this to work before with mappath but am having no luck this time round.

Answer (score 0):

if none of the answers here [How to solve error message: "Failed to map the path '/'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355252/how-to-solve-error-message-failed-to-map-the-path) help, try `Server.MapPath(@".\");`. This and your code worked for me, and produced the same results.