# Windows Server 2012 R2: application pool in IIS stops

Tags: http, iis, iis-8, application-pool, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a dedicated server in Aruba, which is Windows Server 2012 R2 and as you can see from here:

[image]

I created a simple test web site to see if everything works and the relative application pool starts. Anyway, if I perform

```
 http://94.177.162.33 (the IP address assigned to my server from ARUBA) or
 http://localhost
```

I get "Service Unavailable. HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." and I see that the relative application pool test has stopped.
Well, I have never worked with Windows server before and I barely know what is IIS but I wouldn't know hot to solve this issue.
what am I missing?

This is wha I have in Event Viewer:
[image]

Comment: Please look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable

Comment: Thank you for your commet but I had already read that post and it did not help...instead, the solution could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355252/how-to-solve-error-message-failed-to-map-the-path

Comment: I ended up changing the app pool identity for my web service from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "Network Service"

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager > Application pools > choose application pool > Advanced Settings.
2. Scroll down to Rapid Fail Protection and change the option Enabled from True to False. Click OK to apply the changes.
3. Start the Applicaiton Pool