# Feature update to Windows 10, version 1709 affects Visual Studio 2015 IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, iis-express

Development PC with Windows 10 version 1709, Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, .NET Framework version 4.7.02046 and IIS Express.

Custom HTTP Handler (implementation of `IHttpHalder`) in ASP.NET Web Site has stopped working with the following error:

`Failed to map the path '/App_GlobalResources/'.`

Stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/App_GlobalResources/'.] 
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, 
Boolean permitNull) +8965114
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath) +42

System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate2
(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +295


System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate
(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +55
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.RegularAppRuntimeModeInitialize() +174
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +238
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +267
System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags) +224

[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to map the path '/App_GlobalResources/'.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9002835
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333
```

Prior to Windows update to version 1709, the handler was running without problems.

*Please, note the rest of the web site (i.e. static HTML pages etc) are not affected.*

Deleting the site from IISExpress using `appcmd` as per: https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/cleaning-up-iis-express-configuration/ did not fix it.

The purpose of this thread is to assemble all ideas, findings and thoughts on the problem. At best, the source of the problem can be located.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355252/how-to-solve-error-message-failed-to-map-the-path

Comment: @Steve which answer matches this case exactly? I am using IIS Express not IIS. Can you please elaborate?